# How to concatenate two property values into a single data table column for Angular 7 data table? (Ex: first name and last name into one column)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7, angular2-forms

I want to concatenate first name and last name of a person and display it as a Name in a column in my table using Angular 7 data table. Here first name and last name are two different properties.

```
  <data-table [items]="userItems"
                        [itemCount]="userItemCount"
                        [pageLimits]="limits"
                        [limit]="5"
                        (reload)="reloadItems($event)"
                        (rowClick)="onRowClick($event)"
                        (rowDoubleClick)="rowDoubleClick($event)"
                        [rowTooltip]="rowTooltip">
              <data-table-column [property]="'UserId'"
                                 [header]="'UserId'"
                                 [visible]="false">
              </data-table-column>
              <data-table-column [property]="'FirstName'"
                                 [header]="'Name'"
                                 [sortable]="true">
              </data-table-column>
```

Comment: this is angular... angularJS tag is incorrect here

Comment: you can combine firstname and lastname into a new property, and provide that property name to data-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use ng-template, in order to achieve the above requirement.

```
          <data-table-column [property]="'FirstName'"
                                 [header]="'Name'"
                                 [sortable]="true">
                <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item">
                  {{item.FirstName}} <span *ngIf="item.MiddleName != ''"> 
                  {{item.MiddleName}} </span><span>{{item.LastName}}</span>
                </ng-template>
           </data-table-column>
```